# Longest matching substring irrespective of the order of characters

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

I could not find an answer to the following hypothetical interview question:

Given two string sequences of length N, how can you find the maximum length of matching substrings irrespective of order.

For example, given `seq1 = "ABCDEFG"`, and `seq2 = "DBCAPFG"`, the maximum length window is 4. (`ABCD` from `seq1` and `DBCA` from `seq2`).

Comment: By mutated, do you mean the letters can be rearranged?

Comment: @jamylak yes, you are right. Something like anagrams, sequence in another string can be an anagram of sequence in first string, or vice-versa.

Comment: it's called permutation

Comment: I can think of a straightforward N^2 solution, but I'm curious to know  if it can be done any faster.

Comment: What's the max window for ABCD and BCDE?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat we need to find that max-window, in which all the characters are same.Not sure if you got the question right

Comment: @Amit: and DE is (I take it) asking what the max window for those two strings is.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat sorry, the max-window is zero, since the characters are not same in that window

Comment: It's a window shift (given a fixed input means we have fixed window size), then on each shift we check: `intersection(window,key) = union(window,key) ?` by considering that a String is a set of letters

Answer (score 8):

Here is an O(n) solution (assuming fixed alphabet size and O(1) dictionary access).

Use a single frequency table that counts up for characters in seq1, and down for characters in seq2.  We will have a matching window if this histogram ever takes same value again (as this means that we must have identical numbers of intermediate characters).

So we use a dictionary to store previous values for the histogram.

Python implementation:

```
def find_window(seq1,seq2):
    """Yield length of matching windows"""
    D={} # Dictionary with key=histogram, value = first position where this happens
    H=[0]*26 # H[x] is count of x in seq1 - count of x in seq2
    D[tuple(H)]=-1
    for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(seq1,seq2)):
        a=ord(a)-ord('A')
        b=ord(b)-ord('A') 
        H[a]+=1
        H[b]-=1
        key=tuple(H)
        if key in D:
            yield i-D[key]
        if key not in D:
            D[key]=i

print max(find_window("ABCDEFG","DBCAPFG"))
```

If you had a larger alphabet you could use a similar technique only storing a hash value instead of the full histogram.  For example you could simply pick a random code for each character and add on the code for each letter in seq, or subtract for letters in seq2.

You would need a second pass to check that proposed matches were correct in case of a hash collision.

Comment: I don't know the python and usually I cannot understand the algorithm by code. It's better to explain your algorithm in plain text. Then we can see if is correct or not (upvote or downvote respectively).

Comment: Peter, this code seems to work only when the windows start of at the same distance from starting of the string i.e. both of them start from 0th, or 3rd or ith index. If you try this algo with the two strings - "XABCDEFGYZ","YZDBACPFGX", this algo will give 0 maximum window. Note that in this case the windows are starting from 2nd and 3rd index respectively.
If we run one more outer loop, running this algo by incrementing the index for the next string by 1 in every iteration, then it will give the correct result.

Comment: @texens Have you seen the clarifications in the comments to the main question?  Amit says that the max window between ABCD and BCDE is 0, so I think that in your case as well the correct answer is indeed zero.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz you got me wrong, in case of "ABCD" and "BCDE", window is zero since "A" is missing, in "XABCDEFGYZ","YZDBACPFGX" ,the max_window should be 4 (1-4 in str1, and 2-5 in str2)

Comment: @texens Apologies, I don't understand the question after all.  Perhaps Amit could post some simple brute force code to illustrate correct operation?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz the brute-force method will be:                    foreach substring in StringA                                                 foreach substring in StringB if the two are anagrams, find the length of this substring, we need maximum length of such sub-strings.                                                         Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: Here is the brute force implementation, without any optimization :

http://pastebin.com/3Db11jvQ

Comment: @texens Thanks for the code - the thing that puzzles me is that Amit has said that the answer for find_windows("ABCD","BCDE") should be zero.

Comment: I'm guessing that was by mistake. @Amit : Could you please confirm that the max window for "ABCD" and "BCDE" would be 3 i.e. "BCD" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Asumptions**

For given arrays A[0..n], B[0..m]

- Finite alphabet
- Non-repeating characters

  ```
   ans = -1
   j = index of A[0] in B
   if j > n then no substring exists
   for 1 .. n
       find A[i] in B[0..j]
       if not found
           j = find A[i] in B[j+1..m]
           if not found, return last ans
       else 
           if i == j then ans = j
  ```

if B[0..j] were sorted (perhaps construct binary tree P), then searches for A[i] in B[0..j] would be O(log n) and the entire algorithm would be O(n log n)

Help validating this would be great.
Any counterexamples?

Answer (score 0):

It's surely not the optimal algorithm but nobody provided a fully functional solution yet so here's a straightforward approach:

```py
def sort_possible_substrings(p_str):
    """The function iterates through every possible substring of p_str and 
    sorts the characters within the substring and finally inserts them in 
    a set which will be returned."""

    S = set()
    # the possible length of the substrings of p_str
    for s_len in range(1, len(p_str)+1):
        # the substrings of p_str with s_len length
        for s in range(len(p_str)-(s_len-1)):
            sorted_substr = ''.join(sorted(p_str[s:s+s_len]))
            S.add(sorted_substr)
    return S


def longest_common_perm_len(str1, str2):
    """Build up a set from the substrings of the shorter string with the help of 
    sort_possible_substrings. Iterate through the possible substrings of the
    longer string from the longest to the shortest and check whether the same
    string is contained by "candidates" thus by the shorter string."""
    shorter, longer = (str1,str2) if len(str1) <= len(str2) else (str2,str1)
    candidates = sort_possible_substrings(shorter)
    for win_len in range(len(shorter),0,-1):
        for s in range(len(longer)-(win_len-1)):
            str_chunk = ''.join(sorted(longer[s:s+win_len]))
            if str_chunk in candidates:
                return win_len
    return 0
```

(The sorting of the characters within the substrings could be replaced with the "histogram" solution of Peter de Rivaz.)

This not optimal, straightforward algorithm gives:

```
lsubstr.longest_common_perm_len("ABCDZZEFG", "XDBCAXFEG") -> 4
lsubstr.longest_common_perm_len("ABCD", "XDXACXB") -> 1
```